# is there a way to do 4D (linear) interpolation of data with cyclic (angle) coordinates in python?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I need to interpolate a 4D data set (four angles, one output value). Angles are cyclic but scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator can't seem to take this into account. Is there a tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate all of your data at ±2π on each dimension (for 4 dimensions, the easy way of doing this would create 81 copies of each point; the slightly harder way would create 16 copies, by adding 2π to the angles between 0 and π, and subtracting 2π from the angles between π and 2π). That should ensure that every point you query (with all of the angles between 0 and 2π) will have neighbors "on both sides" in each dimension, for the linear interpolation to work with.

Comment: thank you. beautifully simple solution.